# Prevent looping execution of cloud function (python) after modifying JSON values in GCS

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-storage

My cloud function need to update the content only in JSON file in the GCS bucket. Along with Json file there are CSV files also will be uploaded in GCS bucket from another Cloud Function.

I have created a Google CF in python and it is not running as expected. What I guess is my cloud function is keep on running I think this is due to after updating the json file in the same bucket CF understand that `Storage trigger as Finalized`.

Actually my CF should run if `my_jsonfile.json` is uploaded in GCS bucket and then update empty objects with unique identifier (id) and save back in same GCS. My function is updating with ID but it is keep on running for sometime. Let me know how to prevent looking execution in my case. The expectation is, my CF should run when json file is uploaded and modify the content in it and save back to GCS bucket.

This is my try:

```
def hello_gcs(event, context):
    #gcs_file_name = event['name']
    bucket_name = event['bucket']
    folder_name, file_name = event['name'].split('/')
    blob_json_file = folder_name + '/my_jsonfile.json'

    if file_name == 'my_jsonfile.json':
        json_data, blob = extract_blob_json(bucket_name, blob_json_file)
        for blob_key, blob_val in json_data.items():
            print(blob_key, blob_val)
            if blob_val == "":
                gcs_file_name = folder_name + '/' + blob_key + '.csv'
                file_reference_name = blob_key + '.csv'
                object_blob = create_blob(gcs_file_name, bucket_name, file_reference_name)
                modify_blob_json(json_data, blob, blob_key, object_blob.id)
                print("Object name {} : Corresponding blob ID {} ".format(blob_key, object_blob.id))



def create_blob(gcs_file_name, bucket_name, filename: str) -> Blob:
       :
       : # Some code to get the blob (Internal tool)
       :
    return response

def extract_blob_json(bucket_name, file_name):
    # Extract data and load as json
    storage_client = storage.Client()
    bucket = storage_client.get_bucket(bucket_name)
    blob = bucket.blob(file_name)
    content = blob.download_as_text()
    json_data = json.loads(content)

    return json_data, blob

def modify_blob_json(json_data, blob, blob_key, blob_id):
    json_data[blob_key] = blob_id
    # update back to gcs
    with blob.open("w") as f:
        f.write(json.dumps(json_data))
        f.close()
```

Answer (score 1):

Out of the box, you can't manage discard those events! With Cloud Storage, when you "modify" an object, you, in fact, override the current one, it's a write.

And because your event is "Finalized", when the write is finalized, you get an undistinguishable event (first write or update it's the same WRITE).

---

You have 2 solutions here:

- Use a different bucket when you write your updated JSON. That's a good practice to keep the original and the transformed one in case of issue and investigation
- Use Cloud Run (very similar to Cloud Functions, the migration is not a concern) with Eventarc and the [path pattern feature (in preview)](https://cloud.google.com/eventarc/docs/path-patterns). Path pattern will listen the event from ONLY a certain path in the bucket, and not the whole bucket. Sure you still need to store your JSON in another location (another path) but you can keep the same bucket.

In any case, the source and destination must be different.